# How do I solve two equations where one equation has a variable that takes a range of values?

Tags: excel, vba

Two equations ---

c + w + u = 50; 
c-w/4 = 39

In the above, 'u' takes integer values from 0 to 11. (Why/How the 11? 11 = 50-39).

I need to output a table of values for c and w for each value of u starting with u = 0. The corresponding value of u must also appear across each row of values for c and w.

How do I write a VBA code for this?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Do a little algebra first:

```
c-w/4 = 39
c = 39+w/4
c+w+u = 50
39+w/4+w+u = 50
w/4+w+u = 50-39
w/4+w = 11-u
1.25*w = 11-u
w = (11-u)/1.25
```

Put the u values in column **A**.  In **B1** enter:

```
=(11-A1)/1.25
```

and copy down.  In **C1** enter:

```
=39+B1/4
```

and copy down.

The `w` values are in column **B** and the `c` values are in column **C**.